# Append a letter to a page number in Index

Tags: formatting, makeidx

I am writing a book and would like to format an index, in which certain page numbers would have a letter appended (f for figure, t for table, etc.).
I have tried the following short working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
First thing\index{first| f} first.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

but this gives the index entry like:

> first,   f1

My desired output would be:

> first,   1f

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\newcommand{\toback}[2]{#2#1}
\makeindex
\begin{document}
First thing\index{first| \toback{f}} first.
\printindex
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\index{first|toback{f}}`, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

What comes after `|` is interpreted as a command name, so what you get is

```
\item first, \ f{1}
```

which is not what you want.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makeidx}

\newcommand{\figpage}[1]{#1f}
\newcommand{\tabpage}[1]{#1t}

\makeindex

\begin{document}

First thing\index{first|figpage} first.
Second thing\index{second|tabpage} first.

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Note: no space after `|`.

[image]